# use Android CvCameraViewListener2 for detecting object coordinates real-time for further processing without displaying camera images

Tags: android, camera, android-custom-view

I want to detect objects and their coordinates from live-video fed by a phone's camera on Android and use the coordinates to move sprites on an otherwise white canvas.
So far, object detection using a combination of CvCameraViewListener2 and openCV works fine, processing the images provided in the onCameraFrame() method with openCV tools.
However, I don't want to display the image on the screen, but just pass the coordinates of the object detected to a different View to position a sprite on a canvas.

Does anyone have an idea on how to accomplish this in Android 7+?

Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV usually uses **SurfaceView**-based **CameraBridgeViewBase** to work with the camera. Hiding this view may be unreliable. It's safer to switch to **TextureView**-based approach. Then, you have much better control of transparency of this view, and/or easily cover it with another view (the canvas?) to hide it completely.

See the following [Gist](https://gist.github.com/VerachadW/955ed1469be84162be9a) for example.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promising. Do you by chance have an example on how to stack multiple views on top of each other?

Comment: If your view is defined in XML layout inside a FrameView, then any view that belongs to the save FrameView after it, will visually cover your view.